# remove duplicate rows from a csv file using pandas and save the non duplicate rows to a new file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates

Currently, it saves all new info brought in plus it adds `previous_data`. I need `new_data` to only contain data that was found while running the script.

```
    
    deduplicated_data.to_csv('unique_seller_data.csv', index=False)

    try:
        previous_data = pd.read_csv(f'unique_seller_data{last_date_str}.csv')
        new_data = sellers_data[~sellers_data.isin(previous_data)].dropna()
        new_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('no old data to compare to')
        deduplicated_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
        print(f'{len(deduplicated_data)} rows added to new_data_added.csv')
```

If unique_seller_data.csv has **1234**, and previous_data had **1 2 3** then `new_data` should have **4**. But if unique has **1 5 3 4** 2 and previous_data had **1342** then new data should have **5**.

Here is another code I tried that wasn't working either:

```
    
    deduplicated_data.to_csv('unique_seller_data.csv', index=False)

    try:
        previous_data = pd.read_csv(f'new_data_added_{last_date_str}.csv')
        new_data = deduplicated_data[~deduplicated_data.isin(previous_data)].dropna()
        new_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('no old data to compare to')
        deduplicated_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
    print('formatted')
```

I tried merging but got an error:

```
line 1387, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

any help is very appreciated

Already wrote in detail but...

```
    
    deduplicated_data.to_csv('unique_seller_data.csv', index=False)

    try:
        previous_data = pd.read_csv(f'unique_seller_data{last_date_str}.csv')
        new_data = sellers_data[~sellers_data.isin(previous_data)].dropna()
        new_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('no old data to compare to')
        deduplicated_data.to_csv(f'new_data_added_{date_str}.csv', index=False)
        print(f'{len(deduplicated_data)} rows added to new_data_added.csv')
```

Comment: Could you please attach with the example of your data and its columns? What's your input looks like and what's your desire output

Comment: product, price, seller, rating, review, url


then like 500 rows of data 

the output should be the same headers and info format but it should only contain rows that are in deduplicated_data and not in previous_data

Answer (score 0):

You may use merge function:

```
columns = ['product', 'price', 'seller', 'rating', 'review', 'url']
new_data = deduplicated_data.merge(
    previous_data,
    on=columns,
    suffixes=['', '_previous']
    how='left'
)
# Filter out those do not exist in previous list
new_data = new_data[new_data['product_previous'].isna()].drop(
    columns=[f'{c}_previous' for c in columns]
)
```

I am assuming the `deduplicated_data` have the same columns as `previous_data` and there is no any identifier column the represent the row, so have to lookup on every columns.

I realize you mentioned the error of merging in your question, you may try to align the datatype of both of the dataframes before you carry out the merge operation by using `DataFrame.astype`, you may refer [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for more detail information.

Hope this is useful for you.